# how can i read out multiple csv files and combine them into one using java

Tags: java, csv

I am trying to read multiple csv files (for example 1 with first names and gender and 1 with streetnames or whatever) and create a new csv file with all the information merged but i don't know how i have to do that in Java. At the moment i can read out a csv file and i have hard coded a writer to create a new csv file but now i don't know how to continue.

My first csv file looks like this:

```
anzahl;vorname;geschlecht;position
207;Marie;w;2 ... n records
```

My second file looks like this:

```
STRASSE,STRANAM,HSZ
1,Aachener Str.,1 ... n records
```

Basically if headers don't match, all new header titles(columns) should be added after original header and their values according to that order.

For example the new csv file should look like this:

```
anzahl;vorname;geschlecht;position;STRASSE;STRANAM;HSZ
207;Marie;w;2;1;Aachener Str.;1
```

That's my code right now

```
public void doCsvReading() throws IOException {
    var fileName = "D:/IntelliJ/Offis_Project/src/main/resources/Vornamen_2020_Koeln.csv";

    try {
        var fr = new FileReader(fileName, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        var reader = new CSVReader(fr);

        String[] nextLine;

        while((nextLine = reader.readNext()) != null) {
            for (var e : nextLine) {
                System.out.println(e);
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void doCsvWriting() throws IOException {

    CSVWriter writer = new CSVWriter(new FileWriter("Odin.csv"));

    List<String[]> loki = new ArrayList<>();
    String[] gkvHeader = new String[] {"id_intern",
            "FirstName",
            "LastName",
            "FirstBirthName",
            "LastBirthName",
            "Gender",
            "BirthDate",
            "BirthYear",
            "DeathDate",
            "PlaceNow",
            "StreetNow",
            "HouseNumberNow",
            "PostCodeNow",
            "CityOfBirth",
            "PostCodeBirth"};
    loki.add(gkvHeader);

    String[] row1 = new String[] {"1", "Bob", "Waters", "Bob", "Waters", "m", "09.06.2021", "2021", "", "Oldenburg", "Ammerländer Heerstaße", "15", "26129", "Aurich", "26721"};
    loki.add(row1);

    writer.writeAll(loki);
    writer.close();
}
```

Comment: How is the data in the files related to each other? Why are you reading your file using a BufferedReader but writing using a library (gussing OpenCsv is used)? Can you provide a sample input and the expected output?

Comment: Yeah ure right i am using open OpenCsv (i know why ure confused but that's just my beginnings) and now i changed the method so i use the CsvReader and what i wanna do is that i read 2 seperate csv Files and create a new one where these are merged together

Comment: Please show some sample data form your 3 CSV files, and give an approximation of input files' size (how many rows?), and explain how you intend to mix them. Then we'll be able to help

Comment: How do you want to merge them? Do you have some kind of join ccolumn, somekind of primarykey foreignkey relationships, line wise, i.e appending line no.1 from file1 to line no.1 in file2

Comment: i updated my post to show some sample data of the csv files and how i wanna merge them together. the number of rows in the files shoud be any

Answer (score 0):

You want to combine two CSV files having same number of rows horizontally into one CSV. The code will be very long if you are trying to do this in Java. It’s simple to get this done using SPL, an open-source Java package. Only one line of code is enough:

|  | A |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | >file("result.csv").export@cw(file("1.csv").import@w(;,";").(~|file("2.csv").import@wc()(#))) |

SPL offers JDBC driver to be invoked by Java. Just store the above SPL script as combinecsv.splx and invoke it in Java as you call a stored procedure:

```
…
Class.forName("com.esproc.jdbc.InternalDriver");
con= DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:esproc:local://");
st=con.prepareCall("call combinecsv()");
st.execute();
…
```

Or execute the SPL string within a Java program as we execute a SQL statement:

```
…
st = con.prepareStatement("=>file(\"result.csv\").export@cw(file(\"1.csv\")
    .import@w(;,\";\").(~|file(\"2.csv\").import@wc()(#)))");
st.execute();
…
```